# Ubuntu 18.04.6 Intel Irıs XE

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, brightness, gpu

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 recently.Then I assumed that it is not working properly. So ı have started using 22.04 version. But ı have to use 18.04 cause of ROS melodic. (I have a project to modify). Ubuntu 18.04 can not detect my GPU Irıs XE so it works really bad and I cant adjust the brightness so everyone is a little dark to me :)
If anyone can help ı am open to suggestions. Thanks anyway
Zeynel.

Comment: While this is not a great solution, one option would be to use a virtual machine to run 18.04. This will allow you to run 22.04 as the host and 18.04 with ROS only when you need it.

Comment: The IrisXE was released in 2020, so it's not surprising that a 2018-era kernel does not know how to handle it. Even 18.04 + HWE is probably too old. VM might be the way to go until your old ROS code can run on a newer release of Ubuntu. Reminder: Ubuntu 18.04 community support ends in a few months.